# Como funciona o SqlBulkCopy?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Estou usando em meu projeto a classe [`SqlBulkCopy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) para fazer a inserção de dados em massa. Tudo tem funcionado perfeitamente, mas ao recomendar isso para os meus colegas de trabalho, apesar de comprovarem a eficiência, questionaram sobre o funcionamento.

Em minhas pesquisas, pude verificar que o `SqlBulkCopy` trabalha semelhante ao [**utilitário bcp**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms162802(v=sql.120).aspx). Então fui atras de informações, mas não encontrei nada muito detalhado.

Para entender melhor, iniciei o `SQL Server Profiler` para tentar capturar as querys geradas, mas para minha surpresa, aparentemente os dados que foram inseridos não foram enviados via comando SQL.

Agora fiquei ainda mais confuso. O `SqlBulkCopy` trabalha com algum tipo de serviço disponibilizado pelo **utilitário bcp**, enviando para ele os dados à serem inseridos? Como é feito esse trabalho de inserção em massa? Como isso pode ser tão rápido?

Durante a inserção dos dados, existe algum risco das tabelas ficarem travadas? E se ocorre algum erro durante o processo, como ele se comporta?

Answer (score 5):

> O `SqlBulkCopy` trabalha com algum tipo de serviço disponibilizado pelo **utilitário bcp**, enviando para ele os dados à serem inseridos?

[O fonte da classe `SqlBulkCopy` está aqui](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Data.SqlClient/src/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlBulkCopy.cs). Pesquisa por `INSERT BULK` dentro deste fonte. É a forma que ele usa para realizar a inserção.

> Como é feito esse trabalho de inserção em massa?

[Através de um comando parecido com este aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188365(v=sql.120).aspx).

> Como isso pode ser tão rápido?

O SQL Server pula uma série de verificações e simplesmente aceita os dados como corretos, o que torna uma simples operação organizada de escrita, muito mais rápida que uma inserção tradicional.

> Durante a inserção dos dados, existe algum risco das tabelas ficarem travadas?

Elas ficam travadas parcialmente. *Bulk Insert* pede *lock* exclusivo em uma partição na tabela, mas há ainda a opção de *lock* exclusivo [(veja aqui sobre `TABLOCK`)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188365(v=sql.120).aspx).

> E se ocorre algum erro durante o processo, como ele se comporta?

Depende de como você executa isso. Se for dentro de uma transação definida por você, um erro rola para trás todas as modificações. Se for sem uma transação definida, cada *batch* executado com sucesso recebe um *commit* transacional, e um *rollback* caso haja erros. Ou seja, em caso de *batches* com sucesso e *batches* com falha, a inserção será parcial.