# Forma mais rápida de se salvar várias entidades com Entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou com um o problema de performance em um metódo, além de causar o uso total do `CPU` do servidor esse método demora muito a ser executado.

```
 internal async void NotificacaoIosTodos(string titulo, int posicao, int unidadeId)
    {
        try
        {
            _contexto.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            _contexto.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;

            var unidade =  _contexto.Unidade.FirstOrDefault(l => l.UnidadeId == unidadeId);
           var pessoas =  _contexto.PessoaUnidade.Include(l => l.Pessoa)
                .Where(l => l.Pessoa.Dispositivo == (int)enumDispositivo.Ios && l.UnidadeId == unidadeId)
                .ToList();
            var quantidadeAdicionada = 0;

            Notificacao notificacao = new Notificacao { Posicao = posicao };
            _contexto.Notificacao.Add(notificacao);

            foreach (PessoaUnidade pessoa in pessoas)
            {

                PessoaNotificacao pessoaNotificacao = new PessoaNotificacao
                {
                    Visualizado = false,
                    PessoaUnidade = pessoa,
                    Notificacao = notificacao
                };
                _contexto.PessoaNotificacao.Add(pessoaNotificacao);



            }


        await _contexto.SaveChangesAsync();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             throw;
        }

    }
```

O problema e que tenho que inserir aproximadamente `1700` registros de uma vez, quando executo o método `dbContexto.SaveChanges()` ou `dbContext.SaveChangesAsync()`, demora mais de 10 minutos para finalizar, causando `timeout`.

Eu procurei sobre o assunto e achei algumas opções como por exemplo [esta resposta do StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework), eu deixei salvando de 400 em 400 registros e criava um nova instância do `dbContext` , porem não ajudou na performace, ainda demorava mais de 10 minutos.

Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer esse método ser executado de forma mais rápida, não tenho nem ideia para onde seguir, ficaria feliz com qualquer dica ou explicações.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/133553/como-funciona-o-sqlbulkcopy

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92884/erro-ao-inserir-dados-no-banco-ef-6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SqlBulkCopy - muito rápido!

Recomendo utilizar, veja qui um exemplo:
[Sql Bulk Insert for Entity Framework 6](https://gist.github.com/Boggin/763dbaf1b760bb298156)

Referência do recurso: [SqlBulkCopy Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Para melhorar a o desempenho de um modo geral**

**Lazy Load**

```
_contexto.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
_contexto.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

As propriedades que se referem a outro objeto devem ser declaradas como **virtual**:

```
public partial class Pessoa
{
   public virtual ICollection<Contato> Contatos { get; set; }
}
```

Referência: [Lazy Loading](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/lazy-loading-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: só fiz a edição da sua resposta, porque, o site segue um padrão, qualquer duvida siga a [ajuda avançada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @VirgilioNovic obrigado!

Comment: Me explique como o `Lazy Load` pode ser mais rapido que o `Eager Load`?

Comment: @TobiasMesquita porque vc carrega somente o que precisa. Ex.: **Entidade A** possui um ou vários relacionamento **um para muitos** com outras entidades, mas para uma certa View eu preciso somente dos dados da **Entidade A**, porque trazer todos os relacionamentos? Então com lazy Load eu posso controlar isso, carrego somente o que vou usar.

Comment: Estou estudando esse examplo que você referênciou mas estou com um pouco de dificuldade em entender o funcionamento do SqlBulkCopy. o resto eu já havia feito (Lazy Load, e a remoção das verificações).

Comment: Por fim eu acabei utilizando SqlBulkCopy, então resolvi aceitar a sua resposta, era bom se você adiciona-se um exemplo de uso, vou tentar editar quando tiver algum tempo.

Answer (score 7):

Tem 4 opções, eu escolheria a 4:

**1 - Utilizar Bulk Insert**
Existe uma extensions para o Entity que promete uma boa melhora na performance http://entityframework-extensions.net/overview

**2 - Não utilizar EntityFramework para esta operação**
Poderia utilizar Dapper ou StoredProcedure - (Indico o Dapper)

**3 - Mudar a implementação**
Ao invés de adicionar notificação para todos os usuários você poderia adicionar uma notificação com um FLAG indicando que é para todos, quando o usuário 'solicitar' a notifação faria a verificação se ele já leu a notificação.
*Implementação*
Pensando em banco relacional seriam criadas 3 tabelas.

Notificacoes para armazenar informações das notificações e dos usuários que devem receber a notificacão, colocaria tipos de notificação, como exemplo: TODOS (notificar todos usuários), GRUPO(grupo específico definido em regras de negócio), USUÁRIO (um único usuário).

Usuários_Notificados - armazenar quais notificações foram entregues. Quando o usuário receber a notificação geraria um registro nesta tabela informando que a notificação X foi entregue para o usuário Y. Assim conseguiria saber qual notificação um determinado usuário deve receber através de uma consulta na em todas as notificações que estão em grupos que o usuário participa e que não existem na tabela de Usuarios_Notificados.

**4 - Utilizar Notifications HUb ou SignalR**
Como aparentemente você está querendo criar PushNotification seria mais indicado você implementar com SignalR ou utilizando o serviço da Azure
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/

Comment: Eu ate uso um sistema de notificação, `OneSignal` , mas tivemos problemas com a entrega de um dados adicionais quando o aplicativo esta em segundo plano, então  foi feito essa rotina para salvar algumas informaçoes, como posição do menu e se ja foi visualizada, eu crio apenas uma notificação e faço a ligação para cada cliente para verificar se esta visualizada, não entendi como eu faria a 3 opção.
 Vou tentar a opção 1 e fazer alguns teste para ver qual seria o ganho , vou fazer testes com a segunda opção também e verificar a posibilidade de trocar o `OneSignal`  para um do citados. Obrigado!

Comment: Cuidado [http://entityframework-extensions.net/overview](http://entityframework-extensions.net/overview) É PAGO!

Comment: O **Bulk insert** resolveu meu problema, vale resaltar que os comandos       `_contexto.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;` e 
     `_contexto.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`também fazem uma boa diferença no desempenho. Muito obrigado por ter respondido me ajudou muito.

Comment: Como dito pelo @EdvaldoSilva o Bulk Insert é pago e apos 1 mês de uso ele passa a lançar um excessão para que você compre a versão completa.